# Prepopulate Okta username in okta login page when user access Salesforce SP initiated SSO URL

Tags: okta, salesforce-communities

I have SAML SSO enabled between Salesforce and Okta(OIE).
I have Salesforce link embedded in email sent to user. When the user clicks this link, user is redirected to okta login page. We would like to auto populate okta username in okta signin page on click of salesforce link in the email.

Okta populates the username if i hit this URL directly and this works.

```
https://example.okta.com/login/login.htm?username=johndoe@example.com
```

So i tried to add this to Salesforce URL in 2 ways as shown below. This doesnt work. Okta query param is lost when SAML request is initiated during this flow.

```
https://example.salesforce.com?so=https://example.okta.com/login/login.htm?username=johndoe@example.com

https://example.force.com?startURL=https://example.force.com/mycompany/s/new-application?recordId=b544u56783KKIq&un=johndoe@example.com
```

Any insights?

Comment: https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D54z00007mQcEeCAK/does-okta-support-pre-filling-username-from-authn-request-during-saml-single-sign-on

Comment: so this is not possible even with okta custom domain and custom signin widget?